# Virtuoso installation stuck on "VAD Sticker vad_dav.xml creation" on 2nd attempt

Tags: virtuoso, openlink-virtuoso

I've been attempting to install virtuoso-opensource as per the README here: https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource

The first time I ran `make`, it breezed passed "VAD Sticker vad_dav.xml creation" to "Starting Virtuoso Server" and then complained `netstat: command not found`.

I installed netstat via `sudo apt-get install net-tools`, ran `make` again and now it's always stuck on "VAD Sticker vad_dav.xml creation" even after starting from scratch after deleting the repo folder and re-cloning it again. `make install` gets stuck at the same point.

Does anyone have any ideas as to how to get past this?

I'm running Ubuntu Server 20.04.1 LTS on an AWS EC2 instance.

Comment: I would suggest you raise this issue directly on the [Virtuoso project on Github](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/issues), where you'll get much faster response from the programming team as well as other users of that codebase. You could also raise it on the [OpenLink Community Forum](http://community.openlinksw.com/), for similar reasons. That said -- are you trying to build `/develop/7` or a different branch? I'm confused about why you re-ran `make` after installing `netstat`, since you had already built `virtuoso` successfully, to get the `netstat: command not found` error…

Answer (score 0):

I'll note the requirement for netstat to build VADs.

By far the most common cause of hang at that stage is a stagnant virtuoso pid lurking.

`pkill virtuoso` and run `make` again.

HTH

Comment: This actually appears to be a duplicate of [issue #930](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/issues/930)... where the same advice was given, with successful result.